# get last x items (which are true) in logical vector

Tags: matlab

I have a simple problem and was wondering if there's a quicker way (i.e. a one-liner or less lines of code) to get *the last X values that are true* from a logical vector.

here's what I have:

```
%define variables
vec=logical([0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1]);
lastX=3;
%my approach
idx=find(vec); %find indices of values that are true
idx=idx(end-lastX+1:end); %find last X true values
vec(setxor(1:size(vec,2),idx))=0; %get values that are not in idx, set them false
vec %display output, should report [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make an easy one-liner by using the extra arguments for [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) (specifying the number of values to find and which end to find them from) and then getting the [minimum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) index returned:

```
vec(1:(min(find(vec, lastX, 'last'))-1)) = false;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) to count the number of occurrences of `true` starting from the end of the vector to the beginning by using the `'reverse'` direction flag. If the count is greater than your desired `lastX`, that element in `vec` should be `false`:

```
vec(cumsum(vec, 'reverse') > lastX) = false;
```

Comment: Nice. Probably not as efficient as `find`, but it would win a round of code golf. ;)

Comment: @gnovice Hehe... yeah, 3 full passes through the vector will probably take longer than two partial passes. Also, this solution unfortunately doesn't work in Octave since the direction flag hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: In octave you could use `flip`, though I guess that adds two passes through the vector.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, far too many characters for code golf, too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html). Probably very inefficient; mostly for fun:

```
vec(1:regexp(char(vec+'0'),[repmat('10*',1,lastX) '$'])-1) = false;
```